# Having trouble sending to Gmail SMTP using javax.mail

Tags: java

I want to send a mail using Gmail's SMTP server. Can you tell me why it won't connect to server when I run the bellow code.

```
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendTrick {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "465");
    props.put("mail.from", "example@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    try {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom();
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                          "ex@gmail.com");
        msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
        msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
    }
  }
}
```

The exception in the log is

> send failed, exception: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>    connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;   nested exception is:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Carefully look at your properties map, especially `mail.smtp.host`...

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be authenticating with the server.  Is this a deliberate ommision?

Comment: Can you connect to that host and port via a telnet client?

Comment: @home don't be so cryptic :)  Perhaps this ought to be an answer?

Comment: infect in my programm I mentioned the correct gmail address...So what I need to do ?

Comment: have u included that mail provider jar file??

Answer (score 4):

You are not setting a `mail.smtp.port` since there is a duplication typo on the property `mail.smtp.host`, therefore the default port 25 is being used, as detailed in the the Exception.

GMail's SMTP is not running on port 25, which is why the connection is being refused. From [Set up POP in mail clients](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287), it looks like it should be 465 or 587, so you have a valid value but the property key is incorrect.

**Edit:**

You need use the correct *property key* for the port:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); // <-- use the word "port", not "host"
```

After this is fixed, you may also find authentication issues, as already noted in the comments, unless you have purposely left out the `javax.mail.Authenticator` code in the question.

**Edit 2:**

As I mentioned, you might need to specify additional properties to successfully authenticate and be authorised with the SMTP server, for example:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

But, since you are using port 465 for SSL connection you will also need to specify additional SSL properties such as the `mail.smtp.socketFactory.class`.

Comment: even if mentioned it as gmail port "465",  shows like  send failed, exception: "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"  thanks

Comment: Very carefully read the `port: 25` part of the exception. It is showing that you are trying to connect on port 25.

Comment: I coded  'props.put("mail.smtp.host", "465");' so what I need to do here Andyb.. even 587 not working.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. But It shows again like **send failed, exception: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c1sm4335324pay.19'**

Comment: I have updated my answer again but it is not clear if you want to connect using STARTTLS or SSL. You are using the SSL port but have not included any SSL specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps:**

1. Disable "Two factor authentication" in Your Email
2. Navigate to: "https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1" and turn on "Access for less secure apps"
3. Download JavaMail API "https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html" and Add it to your library

**CODE**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class email_try {
 public static void main(String ap[]) {
  String myEmail = "YOUR EMAIL";
  String password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
  String opponentEmail = "THEIR EMAIL";
  Properties pro = new Properties();
  pro.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  pro.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  pro.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  pro.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  Session ss = Session.getInstance(pro, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   @Override
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(myEmail, password);
   }
  });
  try {
   Message msg = new MimeMessage(ss);
   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(myEmail));
   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(opponentEmail));
   msg.setSubject("Your Wish");
   msg.setText("java email app");
   Transport trans = ss.getTransport("smtp");
   Transport.send(msg);
   System.out.println("message sent");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

TRY THIS CODE AND PUT CORRECT EMAIL ID AND PASSWORD﻿